# TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__',python

Tags: python

How do I fix this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "l3.py", line 45, in <module>
z = solve_minmax(n, a, B, x_min=-1000, x_max=1000)
File "l3.py", line 33, in solve_minmax
    dot_B_x = pulp.lpSum([B[i][j] * x[j] for j in range(n)])
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: probably want to post codes here?

Comment: you should show some code

Answer (score 8):

The `__getitem__` is a special python function which is equivalent to the operator `[]` or the indexing or the "get item" operator.

So, the error is basically saying that there is a variable which is a float. And to this variable you've called the `__getitem__` function - probably by doing an index operator to it.

Based on the traceback which shows the line `dot_B_x = pulp.lpSum([B[i][j] * x[j] for j in range(n)])` as the culprit, it seems either B, B[i], or x would be the probable issue

Answer (score 4):

`pulp.lpSum([B[i][j] * x[j] for j in range(n)])`

`TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Which means that either `B`, `B[i]` or `x` are floats, and you can't use `[]` on these.