# python not being able to access values from list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a simple code:

```
with open('trace.txt') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        parts = line.split()
        lines = float(parts[1])

print lines[0]
```

but I'm getting error, for not being able to access the float in the list:

```
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

What's the best explanation for the error and how to fix this?

Comment: What list? I don't see a list ;/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341026/typeerror-float-object-has-no-attribute-getitem-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: could you add the trace.txt?

Comment: just change print `lines[0]`  to print `lines` and you are good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot print an element of a float, because float is not a list and therefore does not implement __getitem__.

```
lines = []
with open('trace.txt') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        parts = line
        lines.append(float(parts[1]))

print lines[0]
```

If you want to print an element of your list you can access it with the index.

Comment: Thank you so much . I'm new to this

Comment: No problem, we all started somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are overwriting the variable `lines` every loop iteration with the value of the float. Instead you want to append it to a list called `lines`:

```
lines = []
with open('trace.txt') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        parts = line.split()
        lines.append(float(parts[1]))

print lines[0]
```

Comment: Thank you . This is what I'm missing . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('trace.txt') as inf:
    lines = [float(parts[1]) for line in inf for parts in line.split()]
print lines[0]
```